# How to switch to a different window using selenium webdriver java?

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to switch to a New window which gets displayed when I click on the Debt Pricing Template. But I am unable to do that as a result of which I am not able to proceed with further scripting... The problem is I am not able to know what should I pass in the `switchTo.window()` because Pricing Approval Gateway window displays and following is the HTML for the new window:

```
<*h1 class="pageType noSecondHeader">Pricing Approval Gateway<*/h1>
```

Following is the code:

```
LoginPage2.driver.findElement(By.linkText("TEST ORG")).click();

System.out.println("3.Select Dept pricing template button from the organization detail page.");

if(LoginPage2.driver.findElement(By.name("debt_pricing_template")).isDisplayed())

System.out.println("User should able to navigate to Dept pricing template and template display few question, user have answer these question for further navigation.");

LoginPage2.driver.findElement(By.name("debt_pricing_template")).click();

LoginPage2.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

LoginPage2.driver.switchTo().window("bPageTitle");
```

Please advise what needs to be added?

Answer (score 0):

I never used it because in my tests I am not using any new windows, but this should help:

```
Set<string> handlers = driver.getWindowHandles();  
 if (driver.getWindowHandles().size()>= 1){  
   for(String handler : handlers){  
    driver.switchTo().window(handler);  
    if (driver.getElement(By.tagName("h1")).contains("Pricing")){  
      System.out.println("Get focus on Popup window");  
      break;  
    }  
   }  
 }  
 else System.out.println("No windows founded!");
```

I am not quite sure with the h1 approach. So if it does not help, try before opening new window storing current window to String:

```
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Then click the link (or do something else as you are doing now)  to open new window. Then to switch to the new window:

```
 Set<string> handlers = driver.getWindowHandles();  
 for (String handler : handlers){
    if (!handler.equals(mainWindow)){
      driver.switchTo(handler);
      break;
    }
 }
```

And then to switch back to original window just do:

```
driver.switchTo(mainWindow);
```

Ofcourse the `driver` variable is expected live instance of 
`WebDriver`

Comment: Hi Djangofan, I tried the same its not working kindly help... I am stuck with this issue

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Go to Billing Summary")).click();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("01 Mar 2016")).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.linkText("AMS TAX")).click();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("00842")).click();

Set<String> instancewindow= driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = instancewindow.iterator();
    String parent =it.next();
    String child = it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(child);

driver.switchTo().frame("modalSubWindow");

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("View More Vehicle Details>>")).click();
    driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```

Comment: Please execute the code which i supplied and then rate it. plz.